# google analytics API tables structure

Tags: api, google-analytics

I am trying to load data from google analytics through the API.

The data that I need is a list of all the landing page and the Facebook ad id (The pages are lunching from FB ad campaign).

In which tables i can find this data? I need to load it on a daily basis and to connect it to the cost data of FB.

Thanks, D.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please take a look here and edit your question -> stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask